# Compressing a PDF response in Java REST web service?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, pdf

I am returning a PDF document from my Java RESTful web service but that pdf is of 10 MB.

Here is the code

```
@GET
    @Path("/{docid}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    @Consumes({"application/xml","application/json","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

    public Response getInvoiceDocument(@PathParam("docid") String docObjectId) throws Exception {

        DocumentumService documentumService = new DocumentumService(documentumConfigUtil);
        DocumentumDocumentBean docDocumentBean = documentumService.getInvoiceDocContent(docObjectId, true);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(docDocumentBean.getDocFile());
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) fileInputStream);
        responseBuilder.type("application/pdf");
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=test.pdf");
        return responseBuilder.build();
```

Is there any way to compress the PDF and then send in response ?

Comment: a good written PDF is already close to deflate-compression, because it uses object and xref streams. So you cannot gain much in adding an additional compression.

Comment: On the other hand it could have other issues despite using streams compression and objects streams. Unused resources like fonts or images and duplicated images resources. Images are also an area where you could gain bytes, depending on the images in the doc and how willing you are to give up quality. You can give a try at [Sejda](https://www.sejda.com/compress-pdf) compress task with some of your docs and see if it manages to reduce the size with an acceptable quality